# Saving slider value to global variable and output to div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a jquery slider, what I want is to get the value from the slider and output it into a div and also save to a global varibale in javascript. It must also do this the moment is slider is moved. So far I have:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Brush Size</p>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="Total">0</div>
  </div>


  var brushSize;




var slider = $('#slider').slider({ 
    steps: 100,
    handle: $('.knob'),
    animate:'true',
    min:1,
    max:100,
    startValue: 1,
    change: function(e,ui){
        brushSize = ui;

    }
```

I am unsure of where to go from here, its not working yet no errors.
Working example:

http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
brushSize = ui;
```

to

```
brushSize = ui.value;
```

... assuming you set the div with brushSize somewhere else, otherwise you want:

```
$('#Total').html(ui.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple ...

```
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Brush Size</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="Total">0</div>
```

```
var brushSize;

 var slider = $('#slider').slider({ 
steps: 100,
handle: $('.knob'),
animate:'true',
min:1,
max:100,
startValue: 1,
change: function(e,ui){
    brushSize = ui.value;
    $('#Total').html(ui.value);
}
```